# Click to call with a soft phone

Tags: voip, pbx, crm, phone, softphone

I'm trying to set up click to call with a soft phone. I'm using QuteCom for the soft phone, vTiger for the CRM and Asterisk, through Elastix for the PBX.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction for getting that set up. I want like to do it in the simplest way possible. Hopefully, the solution will not involve modifying the Asterisk configuration.

I am using QuteCom currently, but I am willing to use another soft phone, as long as it is open source. I'm willing to use a soft phone that is not open source, but that is not my preference.

I would also like for it to work on both Windows and Linux, if possible.

I would prefer a software solution, preferably open source, that simply transfers the number in the phone field on the CRM to the soft phone when clicked. There has to be something out there. I imagine it is a relatively simple solution.

Comment: Does your softphone register a URL handler with the users' browser? If not, then there's really no hope in this working without interacting with asterisk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register your own URL handler in the browser (how depends on browser) and some softphones have the ability to run on commandline with a number as parameter (certainly the proprietary softphone zultys supply with their systems does). Qutecom dox, limited as they are indicate this:

```
qutecom -c call\123456
```

should work.

The "hard bit" in my experience is making sure the CRM web app presents a number with a url-looking-thing. Im not sure if there's a standard for this, I had our internal system prefix numbers with phone:// - it kinda worked, but was a bit too fiddly all told, so I never put it live. Would be interested to hear how you get on.

Comment: I'm pretty ignorant on this topic, so forgive me if what I say is pretty basic. The CRM, vTiger, already presents phone numbers like a URL. Whenever I click it, it tells me to pick up my extension to make the call. Then it says that the parameters are incorrect. I imagine that I will have to change some setting within vTiger. Is there any way you could point me to a good tutorial, or hint to me how I could go about looking for one?

Comment: Start by having a look at what is registered as the url handler in your browser. Some softphones "ring" you and then you pick up, then the "real" call starts, sounds like that is trying to happen here.

Comment: I magine that I could even bypass vTiger and use Firefox and a Greasemonkey script they already have to accomplish the goal. Thanks for your help.